# Where exactly did they base the locations in Germany and Czech off of in Monster by Madhouse?

Tags: monster

In the anime *Monster* by Madhouse, lots of the scenes are set in either Germany, the Czech Republic, or France. I was wondering if the locations were based off of real places or not.

Unlike with  other anime like K-ON, Higurashi and Hyouka, I wasn't able to find anything about anime pilgrimage locations for Monster on the Internet.

Does anyone know where the locations are based off of?

Comment: This blog [The Garden of Proserpine](https://erich-springer.livejournal.com/) lists many findings with photos as comparison.